# QMediaPlayer Not Loading Media And Not Emitting mediaStatusChanged() Signals

Tags: c++, qt, audio, qt5, qmediaplayer

I've recently started working with Qt and am trying to play a sound file using QMediaPlayer.

My program compiles and runs but the sound file is not played, the QMediaPlayer seems stuck in the `QMediaPlayer::LoadingMedia` state.

Also - and possibly related - the QMediaPlayer doesn't ever seem to emit its `mediaStatusChanged` or its `error` signals (though perhaps this is me not connecting them properly?)

When I run the program as below, it reaches the `while` loop and never leaves. If I query for `player->mediaStatus()` inside the loop, it constantly returns 2 (`QMediaPlayer::LoadingMedia`).

When I run it with the while loop omitted, the program continues to run until it reaches end of execution with no run-time errors but - as you may expect - the file is not played.

Interestingly, the two `cout`s before the `while` loop, which report player's `mediaStatus` and `state` show that the `mediaStatus` changes from 1 (in the first instance, before setting the media) to 2 (after setting the media) but my `ChangedStatus` slot is never called, despite `connect`ing to the `mediaStatusChanged` at the start of the `run` function.

Running: Debian Jessie, Qt5.7/Qt5.9

AudioPlayer.h

```
#include <QThread>
#include <QMediaPlayer>

class AudioPlayer : public QThread {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    AudioPlayer();

public slots:
    void ChangedStatus(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus);
    void MediaError(QMediaPlayer::Error);

protected:
    void run();
};
```

AudioPlayer.cpp:

```
AudioPlayer::AudioPlayer(){}    
void AudioPlayer::run()
{
    QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer();
    connect(player, SIGNAL(mediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus)), this, SLOT(ChangedStatus(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus)));
    connect(player, SIGNAL(error(QMediaPlayer::Error)), this, SLOT(MediaError(QMediaPlayer::Error)));
    std::cout << "Got player!" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "\n\n\tPlayer state: " << player->state() << "\n\tMediaState: " << player->mediaStatus() << std::endl;

    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/home/me/test.wav") );
    std::cout << "Set source" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "\n\n\tPlayer state: " << player->state() << "\n\tMediaState: " << player->mediaStatus() << std::endl;

    while(player->mediaStatus() != QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus::LoadedMedia)
    {//
    }

    player->setVolume(100);
    std::cout << "Set volume" << std::endl;

    player->play();
    std::cout << "Played" << std::endl;    
}    
void AudioPlayer::MediaError(QMediaPlayer::Error error)
{
    std::cout << "Media Error: " << error << std::endl;
}    
void AudioPlayer::ChangedStatus(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus status)
{
    std::cout << "Status changed to: " << status << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "audioplayer.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    AudioPlayer myAudioPlayer;
    myAudioPlayer.start();
    std::cout << "myAudioPlayer started. Waiting...." << std::endl;
    myAudioPlayer.wait();

    std::cout << "myAudioPlayer returned." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Extra Info:**

Now, initially, I hadn't used QThread and was trying to do this all in `main.cpp` (just declaring a QMediaPlayer and attempting to set the media and play) but this was giving me `QObject::startTimer: timers cannot be started from another thread warning` run-time errors in a couple of places (declaration of the `QMediaPlayer` and, I think, the `play` command), so I adopted the above approach - although I'm not sure that subclassing QThread is, necessarily, the best way. This is also why everything (declarations etc.) is done in the `run` function - having the QMediaPlayer as a  member of AudioPlayer and initialising it in the constructor gave the same error.

I have compiled and run Qt's Player example (from multimediawidgets) and, by browsing and selecting my `test.wav`, it can play the file so I don't think it's a compatibility issue. I looked through the Player example source but couldn't see anything jumping out which I had missed and which looked like the cause of my problem.

Comment: Where is the mandatory QApplication instance? There is no message loop i.e. neither myAudioPlayer.exec() nor QApplication::exec() call some where. So signals can never reach one of your slots.

Comment: @bkausbk thank you for this - it certainly helped get the signals working (see my comment on your answer, below). Unfortunately, I was following [Qt's overview of audio](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/audiooverview.html) which doesn't mention the necessity of QApplication (only mentions needing to creat a media player, set the media source, and play) so I hadn't realised it was mandatory.

Comment: I didn't find an example where `QApplication` is explicitely not used either. It is silently assumed that "QApplication" and corresponding message loop is always present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an QApplication object and use it's message loop. I would suggest you to test following:

```
#include "audioplayer.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    AudioPlayer myAudioPlayer;
    myAudioPlayer.start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

You will at least get your signals raised. If the media state reaches `QMediaPlayer::StoppedState` or any error occured, you could call `QApplication::instance()->quit()` to stop your application.

**Edit:** Better use the new style connections like:

```
connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::mediaStatusChanged, this, &QMediaPlayer::ChangedStatus);
```

It is more reliable and you don't have to register specific parameter types like `QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus` with `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()`

Because `QMediaPlayer` class contains another method called `error` with a different signature, signal connection is a bit more complicated. This is because the compiler don't know which `error` method you are referring to. In this case `static_cast` is the way to solve this ambiguity:

```
connect(
    player,
    static_cast<void(QMediaPlayer::*)(QMediaPlayer::Error )>(&QMediaPlayer::error),
    this,
    &AudioPlayer::MediaError
);
```

Please note, a Wave file is only a container file that can contain an arbitrary compressed data stream. It may be necessary to install the appropriate operating system multimedia codec first. In Microsoft Windows Qt-Framework relies on installed multimedia codecs (.ax file).

Your `AudioPlayer::run` method will end without waiting for the media being played. So you should wait for the `Stopped` status some where before the thread ends. However it is better not to use the `run` method directly but using QThreads message loop instead.

```
class AudioPlayer : public QThread {
public:
    AudioPlayer() : _Player(nullptr) {
        moveToThread(this); // AudioPlayer object become part of this new thread
    }

public slots:

    void setVolume(int);
    void load(QString Media);
    // ...

    void play() {
        // Never directly access any members since they may belong to a different thread
        if (thread() != QThread::currentThread()) {
            QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "play", Qt::QueuedConnection);
        } else {
            _Player->play();
        }
    }

    void stop() {
        quit(); // Quiting thread message loop
    }

private:
    QMediaPlayer* _Player;

    void run() {
        _Player = new QMediaPlayer(this);

        connect(...) // All connections go here...

        int Result = QThread::exec();

        _Player->stop();

        delete _Player;
    }

private slots:

    void HandleStatusChange(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus Status) {
        emit statusChanged(Status); // Redirect so that the main application can handle this signal too
    }

signals:
    void statusChanged((QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. This got the `mediaStatusChanged` signal working as you'd said. Unfortunately the file still never loads - any idea why this may be? 

Also - I had trouble connecting the error signal with the same method you demonstrated for the mediaStatusChanged signal. Compiler complains of an "Unresolved overloaded function type" - is it getting confused with the Error enum or the error property, perhaps?

Many thanks

Comment: Thank you for the further advice. The connection to the `error` is now completed with the `static_cast` - although no errors are produced. And with regards to the file, Qt's Player example can open and play the same file I am trying to use without issue - does this imply that I should be able to play the file also? If not - where would I start looking into codecs? Do you mean "windows codec" as in the Windows OS? Using Debian, is it likely to be any different?

Comment: @cprlkleg: Yes in your case it is no windows operating system multimedia codec, it may be either part of the Linux Qt-Framework or part of some operating system components. I don't know that. If you say that Qt Player example works as intended, you should compare your source with the Qt Players example. Please remove the `while` loop in your QThread `run` method. It is no clean code.

Comment: Thanks again. As mentioned in my initial question, I'm comparing with the Player example as I go, but nothing has jumped out at me as something obvious that I've missed. And with regards to the while loop, it's only there during this debugging phase until I can get something working and playing a file.

I will continue editing what I have and trying the approach illustrated in your most recent update. Thanks

Thank you for your assistance this far.

Comment: Thank you very much! Adopting the use of slots and signals as per your last edit has allowed me to get the file loaded and playing as expect. I'm still not 100% of the actual reason behind my problems, but likely to do with being in a wrong thread when trying to set the media. Using an `if(thread() != QThread::currentThread())` test in the `load` slot - as you illustrated with the `play()` slot - seems to fix this.
Thank you once again
One final question, if you are able: the `moveToThread(this)` call in AudioPlayer constructor... What gets moved to the `this` thread? The program execution?

Comment: @cprlkleg: I'm not exact sure, but I think `QMediaPlayer` instance should be moved to that new thread too. Otherwise each raised signals will be executed in `QApplication` message loop.

Comment: @cprlkleg: Each QObject belongs to one specific thread. With `moveToThread` one can change this thread assignment and predetermines what message loop is used for signal/slot execution. Accessing members in objects that doesn't belongs to the same thread without any interlock mechanism is critical and mostly will cause problems sooner or later. UI object methods (eg QWidget, QTimer, QAbstractSocket ...) can never be called from a different thread than the thread at which this object was created, which is usually the main thread.